# Suddenly unable to install APK generated from Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I have an app that's already published, with a few users, everything has been working fine for the last six months or so and the last version release was 2 months ago.
Last week I changed a few design details (just basic stuff like color and some text) but after I built the apk I've tried to install it on my smartphone and got "a problema parsing the package", tried to install on an emulator and got "device not compatible" even though the last apk version worked fine.
Tried with some of the users devices and the same errors appeared.

Example application with same problem: https://github.com/wurayan/apk_buggy

I have no idea why it would suddenly stop installing on all devices, can anyone help me with this?

```
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19045.3570], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.13.9 on channel stable at C:\Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d211f42860 (3 weeks ago), 2023-10-25 13:42:25 -0700
    • Engine revision 0545f8705d
    • Dart version 3.1.5
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34-ext8, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231)

[√] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.76.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19045.3570]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 119.0.6045.124
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 119.0.2151.44

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

Some more information:

- After the first few failures I updated all dependencies, Flutter SDK and Kotlin Gradle and it still did not work.
- The flutter run --release command works fine.
- Cleaning data, uninstalling previous versions, uninstalling for all users, and even installing on a device that never had the app installed before worked.
- I usually use --split-per-abi and install the armabi-v7a-release, but after some testing I discovered that only the arm64-v8a-release and the fat APK work on the emulator, on the real devices I couldn't get any version to work.
- Now my device won't even install the earlier versions of the app, which worked fine for the last few months.
- I have a Flutter sample application that I used to text some dependencies and compability and even the APK of this application doesn't work (I'll link it here so maybe someone can take a look and find something);
- At first I thought it was a problema specific to my device, but it stopped working on all the devices I tested.
- The APK is built without any errors or warnings.

Comment: Get the latest working APK and extract AndoridManifest.xml (in decoded form). Then compare it to AndoridManifest.xml of a recent APK. You can use Andorid Studio's Analze APK feature to get the APK, or you use one of the common decompilers like JadxGUI or apktool.

Comment: @Robert The version before this problem occurred and the version before I updated all packages (which was the one I encountered the problem) have a total of 638B of difference and both AndroidManifest are exactly the same.
I tried to install a previously released APK, but it also failed to install, which confuses me even more, why would a version that's been in use for months suddenly not work too?